# Linearity and Passivity

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, analog

Are all linear circuits passive in nature? Or is it possible that there is some active element which is also linear?

Here, all elements are considered to be ideal, i.e. they are unlike the elements in physical circuits but rather the lines on a page. Also, please don't consider amplifiers as a whole, as this question is an attempt to understand why we need non-linear elements to construct amplifiers and no amplifier can be created using linear elements only.

In essence, the question is 'Does linearity imply passivity ?'.

Comment: Active components can be operated in a linear fashion or region. eg. amplifiers.

Comment: The question is too vague.  First, you haven't specified whether you mean physical circuits, or lines on a page.  Second, there are no completely linear circuit elements -- if nothing else, things go up in smoke when they're overloaded, and that's not linear behavior.  Third, most amplifiers can certainly be *treated* as linear elements, if you ignore their innards, and their power supplies.

Comment: In addition to everything TimWescott said, Transformer saturation is a other example of passive elements exhibiting non-linear behavior.

Comment: Even resistors cannot be truly regarded as linear (in extremes).

Comment: I thought amplifiers were linear. Why are they not?

Answer (score 2):

the question is 'Does linearity imply passivity ?

No,in pure mathematical sense answer would be No.

Consider an input signal x(t) and a linear system whose output is Y(t)=-2x(t)

Now energy delivered by input = take limit from 0 to t and assuming initial condition zero then energy delivered by input  at time t  would be

E= ∫x(t)Y(t)= ∫x(t).(-2x(t))<=0 for all t>=0 and so it is not a passive system .

And hence linearity doesn't imply passivity.

Anyone interested in edits are welcome as I didn't use MATHML code

Answer (score 0):

The reply to your question "Are all linear circuits passive in nature?" is no, you got that reply already from @user215805

What I want to share with you in here is that the question has no much sense, sorry for saying like that. Linearity and Passivity are two different concepts that have nothing to do one to each other, they are two different taxonomies (classifications) of the circuits or components, same as if you would compare the colour of a fruit with its taste, "are all red fruits sweet?" is a question maybe interesting but with no much sense.

Then, in simply words, a linear circuit is that one that gives in its output a proportional signal of its input and you can get that linearity by using either passive or active components or circuits. And the same applies on the other way around.